# MongoDB index on ref is not taking effect

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following model

```
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        workSpace: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Workspace'
        }
    }
);
```

After getting complains of slow requests, I went over to my MongoDB Atlas dashboard in production and created an `index` on the Post documents like this

```
{
  'workSpace':1
}
```

Yet, when I queried for posts like this

```
let skip=userDefined ?? 0;
let limit=1000;

let postsInWorkSpace = await Post.find({workSpace})
            .sort({ created_at: 'desc' })
            .skip(limit * page)
            .limit(limit);
```

The above query still takes up to 50seconds before returning results.

So, is there something else I need to do to make the above query faster, because right now it seems the index is not working?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

after your schema definition you can try to add this line

```
PostSchema .index({ workSpace: 1 });
```